# Rank of special block matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Given two matrices $A\in \mathbb{R}^{a\times b}$ and $X\in \mathbb{R}^{b\times b}$, can there anything be said about the rank of the block matrix:

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
AX & A
\end{bmatrix}
~,
\end{align*}
provided $X$ is non-singular and $a>b$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the rank of $A$, since the columns of $AX$ are linear combinations of the columns of $A$. The premises that $X$ is non-singular and that $a\gt b$ aren't necessary.

Comment: That's what I wanted to hear, thanks!